# VBA Dynamic array has a bunch of empty values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a filter macro that will filter a table for items and delete rows with that item. This is done by looping through an array which referenced a finite range on reference worksheet.

I am trying to change this array to be dynamic so that I can add or remove items to be deleted without having to open the code.

Before:

```
    Dim ArrCategory   As Variant
    ArrCategory = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:B12")
    For i = 2 To LastRowA
        For Each item In ArrCategory
            If Range("E" & i).Value = item Then
                lo1710.Range.autofilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=item
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                lo1710.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                lo1710.autofilter.ShowAllData
            Else
            End If
            
        Next item
    Next i
```

After:

```
    Dim ArrCategory   As Variant
    ArrCategory = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
    For i = 2 To LastRowA
        For Each item In ArrCategory
            If Range("E" & i).Value = item Then
                lo1710.Range.autofilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=item
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                lo1710.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                lo1710.autofilter.ShowAllData
            Else
            End If
            
        Next item
    Next i
```

After making this change I started getting the "No cells were found" error. When I look in the locals window to see what is in that array, I see the values that are supposed to be in there, but then also hundreds of "empties".

[image]

The code does work to eliminate the rows containing the items in the array.

Comment: Any changes you make to the sheet won't affect the array.

Comment: @BigBen I did not make any changes to the sheet, just how the array is defined

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread and didn't realize the array values are from a separate worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid implicit `ActiveSheet` references. Your `Rows` and `Cells` calls implicitly reference the active sheet, which is not guaranteed to be `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Change

```
ArrCategory = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
```

to

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ArrCategory = .Range("B8:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

and note the `.` in front of `Range`, `Cells`, and `Rows`.

Answer (score 0):

### Reference Non-Blanks

- If there are blank but not empty cells below your data, you could use the following function to reference the correct range.
- It uses the Find method and will fail

  - if the worksheet is filtered,
  - or if there are hidden rows.

**The Function**

```vb
Function SetNonBlankColumn( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set rg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    Set SetNonBlankColumn = rg
End Function
```

**Usage**

- It is assumed that the column range has at least two rows.
- In your code, you could utilize the function in the following way:

  ```
  Dim rg As Range: Set rg = SetNonBlankColumn(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8"))
  Dim ArrCategory As Variant: ArrCategory = rg.Value
  ```
- Also, your worksheet is not qualified, and 'the code will look for it' in the active workbook which may be the wrong one (fix with e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets...`).
- Of course, if the blank but not empty cells are there by accident, select the cell below the last value and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Down</kbd> as many times as needed to hit the bottom row, release, and press <kbd>Del</kbd> to clear the range and continue using your code with the corrections suggested by BigBen.